# Protractor Firefox download file

Tags: file, firefox, download, protractor

I have problem with download excel file with protractor in firefox. I set protractor config file with

```
{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
      "--headless",
    ],
    prefs: {
      'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': false,
        'directory_upgrade': true,
        'default_directory': process.cwd() + "/resources/test/download",
      },

    },
  },
}
```

i run perfect with chrome, but when i set with firefox :

```
{
  browserName: 'firefox',

  acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  'moz:firefoxOptions': {
    args: [
      "--headless"
    ],
    prefs: {
      'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': false,
        'directory_upgrade': true,

        'default_directory': process.cwd() + "/resources/test/download",

      },
    },
  },
},
```

but firefox got error, i think firefox cant read the prefs of firefox . I think it's not working firefox. how can i fix to run with firefox ? 
When i comment "--headless" and i run protractor with firefox , firefox shown me 'save as' dialog. i think it's error reason ? Right? 
Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution for the question!

```
{
 browserName: 'firefox',
 marionette:true,
 acceptInsecureCerts: true,
 'moz:firefoxOptions': {
   args: [
     "--headless"
   ],
   prefs: {
     'browser.download.folderList' : 2,
     'browser.download.dir' : process.cwd() + "/resources/test/download",
     'services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.useDownloadDir' : true,
     'browser.download.useDownloadDir' : true,
     'browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen' :false,
     'browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone':true,
     'browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting' : false,
     'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting' : false,
     'browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force':false,
     'browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete':false,
     'browser.download.manager.useWindow':false,
     'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk' : 'text/plain,text/csv,application/csv;text/comma-separat‌​ed-values;application/excel;application/octet-stream;application/xlsx;application/xls;application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
         },
 },
```

},

```
{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  acceptInsecureCerts: true,
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
      "--headless",
    ],
    prefs: {
      'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': false,
        'directory_upgrade': true,
        'default_directory': process.cwd() + "/resources/test/download",
      },

    },
  },
}
```

We can get firefox's prefs in the link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Download_Manager_preferences

and get mine types of firefox (type of download file in firefox) in the link https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: thank you, however I don't manage to dowload a xml file, it gets all the time open. Do you know why ? I tried adding text/xml but no luck

Comment: you can try **'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk' :** with all xml types which you can find in https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html . such as : 
**'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk' :'application/xml,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.apple.installer+xml,application/atomcat+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,'** . You can try to add in list and run test . Have too much xml types, so I can't write all them in this. You can try and goodluck (Ctrl + F and search 'xml' in browser);